# validation eval() for php 7

Tags: php, eval

The original code is this:

```
$hash_stack = array();
foreach ($values as $key => $val)
{
     array_push($hash_stack, $val['tag']);              
     eval("\$ret[" . implode($hash_stack, "][") . "] = '{$val[value]}';");
     array_pop($hash_stack);
}
```

It works in php5 but not in php7:

I got this error for each item in array:

> Notice: Undefined index: . resultObj][result . in /srv/users/...

I tried to fix it with this:

```
$value = $val['value'];
$implode = implode($hash_stack, "][");
eval("\$ret[" . $implode . "] = '{$value}';");
array_pop($hash_stack);
```

But it's still getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

I get this error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant resultObj - assumed 'resultObj' in
>   /srv/use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because your array keys are plain code rather than strings. You'd have to escape and quote them, but... honestly, I'd get rid of the `eval` altogether.

You should be able to do the same thing with a reference:

```
$hash_stack = array();
foreach ($values as $key => $val)
{
    array_push($hash_stack, $val['tag']);

    $r = &$ret;
    foreach ($hash_stack as $h)
    {
        $r = &$r[$h];
    }
    $r = $val['value'];

    array_pop($hash_stack);
}
```